# Is the following a legit successor function for lambda calculus ? (Church Numeral)

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I have read from the books that, the successor for Church Numerals is of the form:
(\lambda n f x. f (n f x) )

Last night I came up with this:
(\lambda a b c. (a b) (b c) )

I believe it also performs the functionality of a successor function. However I am not 100% positive my reductions are correct. Can someone examine it and tell me?

The following is my reduction: let a church numeral be (\lambda f x. f^n x), where f^n x is actually a short version of (f(f(f(f...(x)))..  It represents the number n. The expected result should be n+1, that is (\lambda f x. f^{n+1} x)

(\lambda a b c. (a b) (b c) )(\lambda f x. f^n x)

= (\lambda b c. ( (\lambda f x. f^n x) b) (b c) )  // a replaced

= (\lambda b c. ( (\lambda x. b^n x) (b c) )       // f replaced

= (\lambda b c. ( (\lambda x. b^n x) (b c) ) // not 100% sure, can I replace x with (b c)?

= (\lambda b c. ( b^n (b c) )

= (\lambda b c. ( b^(n+1) c )

Is this reduction correct, especially from step 3 to 4?
Thanks!

Comment: What you've basically shown, FYI, is that `n f ∘ f` is the same as `f ∘ n f` (when `n` is a Church numeral). This makes sense; each composition of `f` is equivalent to adding 1, so you're showing addition is commutative. _n * 1 + 1 = 1 + n * 1_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. There is no problem with substituting `b c` for `x`. See [the substitution rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Substitution). Although `b` and `c` are bound, they're bound above both terms in question, so they have the same meaning at both places.

Answer (score 0):

A way to understand the two definitions of the successor function is to start from the sum:

```
plus = \n,m,x,y. n x (m x y)
```

then we can define

```
succ1 = \n. plus one n 
succ2 = \n. plus n one
```

where `one = \x,y.x y`

simplifying the two terms, we get

```
succ1 = \n,x,y. one x (n x y) 
      = \n,x,y. x (n x y)
succ2 = \n,x,y. n x (one x y) 
      = \n,x,y. n x (x y)
```